# Spring app running on Cloud foundry failing to start due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer

Tags: java, spring, maven, cloud-foundry

Running into the following issue since I have added `spring-boot-parent`  as the parent in the base pom file. There are no jakarta related dependencies in the project. Attached is the maven dependency tree of the project.

Error stack when deploying to cloud foundry -

```
   2023-02-21T11: 37: 45.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0
] OUT {
   "msg": "The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.",
   "level": "ERROR",
   "written_ts": "1676959665643883000",
   "logger": "org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina",
   "written_at": "2023-02-21T06:07:45.643Z",
   "thread": "main",
   "type": "log",
   "stacktrace": [
      "org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:794)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:695)",
      "\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
      "\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)",
      "\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)",
      "\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)",
      "Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start",
      "\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)",
      "\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)",
      "\t... 13 more",
      "Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:951)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:833)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1424)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1414)",
      "\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)",
      "\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)",
      "\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)",
      "\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)",
      "Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]",
      "\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)",
      "\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)",
      "\t... 8 more",
      "Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)",
      "\t... 6 more",
      "Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer",
      "\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)",
      "\tat java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)",
      "\tat java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2478)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:881)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1384)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1228)",
      "\tat java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)",
      "\tat java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:232)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:203)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1587)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1088)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:779)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5127)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)",
      "\t... 6 more",
      "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1420)",
      "\tat org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1228)",
      "\t... 24 more"
   ]
}
   2023-02-21T11: 37: 45.64+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0
] OUT {
   "msg": "Stopping service [Catalina]",
   "level": "INFO",
   "written_ts": "1676959665645366000",
   "logger": "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService",
   "written_at": "2023-02-21T06:07:45.645Z",
   "thread": "main",
   "type": "log"
}
```

Here is the dependency tree -

```
[DEBUG] com.sap.cloud.cit.ar:com.sap.cloud.cit.ar.runtime:war:2.0.0
[DEBUG]    junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
[DEBUG]       org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test (version managed from 1.3)
[DEBUG]          org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test (version managed from 2.2)
[DEBUG]    org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:2.0.2:test
[DEBUG]       org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:2.0.2:test
[DEBUG]          org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:2.0.2:test
[DEBUG]          org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:2.0.2:test
[DEBUG]    org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:jar:2.0.2:test
[DEBUG]       org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:2.0.2:test
[DEBUG]    org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.9.0:test
[DEBUG]       net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.22:test (version managed from 1.10.20)
[DEBUG]       net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.12.22:test (version managed from 1.10.20)
[DEBUG]       org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
[DEBUG]    org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.29.2-GA:compile
[DEBUG]    javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]    io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-codec-haproxy:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-codec-memcache:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-codec-mqtt:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-codec-redis:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-codec-smtp:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-codec-stomp:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-codec-xml:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-handler-ssl-ocsp:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-transport-rxtx:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-transport-sctp:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-transport-udt:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-transport-classes-kqueue:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-aarch_64:4.1.87.Final:runtime (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.87.Final:runtime (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:jar:osx-aarch_64:4.1.87.Final:runtime (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.87.Final:compile (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]       io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-aarch_64:4.1.87.Final:runtime (version managed from 4.1.87.Final)
[DEBUG]    org.json:json:jar:20220924:compile
[DEBUG]    com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.9.1:compile
[DEBUG]    com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.7.0:compile
[DEBUG]       net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8:compile (version managed from 2.4.7)
[DEBUG]          net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.8:compile
[DEBUG]             org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile (version managed from 1.7.33)
[DEBUG]    org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.14:compile (exclusions managed from [commons-logging:commons-logging:*:*])
[DEBUG]       org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.16:compile (version managed from 4.4.16)
[DEBUG]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.14.2:compile
[DEBUG]       com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.4:compile (version managed from 2.14.2)
[DEBUG]       com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.4:compile (version managed from 2.14.2)
[DEBUG]    org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.25:compile
[DEBUG]       org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.25:compile (version managed from 5.3.25)
[DEBUG]       org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.25:compile (version managed from 5.3.25)
[DEBUG]          org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.25:compile (version managed from 5.3.25)
[DEBUG]    org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.25:test
[DEBUG]    org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.32:compile
[DEBUG]    com.sap.cp.auditlog:audit-java-client-api:jar:2.4.3:compile
[DEBUG]    com.sap.cp.auditlog:audit-java-client-impl:jar:2.4.3:compile
[DEBUG]       com.sap.cloud.security:java-security:jar:2.13.5:compile (version managed from 2.11.13)
[DEBUG]       com.sap.cloud.security:env:jar:2.11.13:compile
[DEBUG]       com.sap.cp.auditlog:auditlog-common:jar:2.2.16:compile
[DEBUG]    com.sap.cloud.sjb:xs-env:jar:1.21.0:compile
[DEBUG]    com.sap.cp.security:credential-store-client-java:jar:1.20.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.14:compile (version managed from 4.5.13)
[DEBUG]       org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:jar:0.7.6:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.8.0:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.tomitribe:tomitribe-http-signatures:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]    com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext.cf:jar:3.9.0:compile
[DEBUG]       com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:jar:3.9.0:compile
[DEBUG]    com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext.cf.impl:jar:3.9.0:compile
[DEBUG]       com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext.impl:jar:3.9.0:compile
[DEBUG]       com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext.internal:jar:3.9.0:compile
[DEBUG]       com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext.validation:jar:3.9.0:compile
[DEBUG]       com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext.utils:jar:3.9.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile (version managed from 3.6)
[DEBUG]    com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext.validation.cf:jar:3.9.0:compile
[DEBUG]    com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa:token-client:jar:2.13.5:compile
[DEBUG]       com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa:api:jar:2.13.5:compile
[DEBUG]       com.sap.cloud.security:java-api:jar:2.13.5:compile (version managed from 2.13.5)
[DEBUG]       com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:jar:2.9.3:compile (version managed from 2.9.3)
[DEBUG]          org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.19.0:compile
[DEBUG]          com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.10.0:compile
[DEBUG]    ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.5:compile
[DEBUG]       ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.5:compile (version managed from 1.4.5)
[DEBUG]    com.sap.hcp.cf.logging:cf-java-logging-support-logback:jar:3.6.3:compile
[DEBUG]       com.sap.hcp.cf.logging:cf-java-logging-support-core:jar:3.6.3:compile
[DEBUG]          com.fasterxml.jackson.jr:jackson-jr-objects:jar:2.13.4:compile (version managed from 2.13.2)
[DEBUG]    org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:compile
[DEBUG]    org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:jar:runtime:0.8.8:test
[DEBUG]    io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:jar:1.0.13:compile
[DEBUG]       io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.27:compile (version managed from 1.0.13)
[DEBUG]          io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.26:compile (version managed from 3.4.26)
[DEBUG]             org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.4:compile (version managed from 1.0.4)
[DEBUG]       io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.27:compile (version managed from 1.0.13)
[DEBUG]       io.projectreactor.netty.incubator:reactor-netty-incubator-quic:jar:0.0.2:runtime
[DEBUG]          io.netty.incubator:netty-incubator-codec-quic:jar:linux-x86_64:0.0.20.Final:runtime
[DEBUG]       io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http-brave:jar:1.0.27:runtime (version managed from 1.0.13)
[DEBUG]          io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-http:jar:5.14.1:runtime
[DEBUG]             io.zipkin.brave:brave:jar:5.14.1:runtime
[DEBUG]                io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-brave:jar:2.16.3:runtime
[DEBUG]                   io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.16.3:runtime
[DEBUG]                      io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:jar:2.23.2:runtime
[DEBUG]    org.cloudfoundry:cloudfoundry-operations:jar:5.9.0.RELEASE:compile
[DEBUG]       org.cloudfoundry:cloudfoundry-client:jar:5.9.0.RELEASE:compile
[DEBUG]          com.squareup.wire:wire-runtime:jar:2.2.0:compile
[DEBUG]             com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.8.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.cloudfoundry:cloudfoundry-util:jar:5.9.0.RELEASE:compile
[DEBUG]          org.atteo:evo-inflector:jar:1.3:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.10.0:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.22:compile
[DEBUG]    commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[DEBUG]    commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[DEBUG]    org.cloudfoundry:cloudfoundry-client-reactor:jar:5.9.0.RELEASE:compile
[DEBUG]       com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.4:compile (version managed from 2.11.4)
[DEBUG]       com.github.zafarkhaja:java-semver:jar:0.9.0:compile
[DEBUG]       io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:jar:0.11.2:compile
[DEBUG]       io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:jar:0.11.2:runtime
[DEBUG]       io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:jar:0.11.2:runtime
[DEBUG]       javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile (version managed from 1.3.2)
[INFO] com.sap.cloud.cit.ar:com.sap.cloud.cit.ar.runtime:war:2.0.0
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:2.0.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:2.0.2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:2.0.2:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:2.0.2:test
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:jar:2.0.2:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:2.0.2:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.9.0:test
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.22:test
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.12.22:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
[INFO] +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.29.2-GA:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-haproxy:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-memcache:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-mqtt:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-redis:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-smtp:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-stomp:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-xml:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-handler-ssl-ocsp:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-rxtx:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-sctp:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-udt:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-kqueue:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos:jar:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-aarch_64:4.1.87.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.87.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-kqueue:jar:osx-aarch_64:4.1.87.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.87.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-aarch_64:4.1.87.Final:runtime
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20220924:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.9.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.16:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.14.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.25:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.25:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.25:test
[INFO] +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.32:compile
[INFO] +- com.sap.cp.auditlog:audit-java-client-api:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.sap.cp.auditlog:audit-java-client-impl:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.security:java-security:jar:2.13.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.security:env:jar:2.11.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sap.cp.auditlog:auditlog-common:jar:2.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- com.sap.cloud.sjb:xs-env:jar:1.21.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.sap.cp.security:credential-store-client-java:jar:1.20.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:jar:0.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.tomitribe:tomitribe-http-signatures:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext.cf:jar:3.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:jar:3.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext.cf.impl:jar:3.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext.impl:jar:3.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext.internal:jar:3.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext.validation:jar:3.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext.utils:jar:3.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext:com.sap.cloud.connectivity.apiext.validation.cf:jar:3.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa:token-client:jar:2.13.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa:api:jar:2.13.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sap.cloud.security:java-api:jar:2.13.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:jar:2.9.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.19.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.sap.hcp.cf.logging:cf-java-logging-support-logback:jar:3.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sap.hcp.cf.logging:cf-java-logging-support-core:jar:3.6.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.jr:jackson-jr-objects:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:compile
[INFO] +- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:jar:runtime:0.8.8:test
[INFO] +- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:jar:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.27:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.26:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.27:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.projectreactor.netty.incubator:reactor-netty-incubator-quic:jar:0.0.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty.incubator:netty-incubator-codec-quic:jar:linux-x86_64:0.0.20.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http-brave:jar:1.0.27:runtime
[INFO] |     \- io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-http:jar:5.14.1:runtime
[INFO] |        \- io.zipkin.brave:brave:jar:5.14.1:runtime
[INFO] |           \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter-brave:jar:2.16.3:runtime
[INFO] |              \- io.zipkin.reporter2:zipkin-reporter:jar:2.16.3:runtime
[INFO] |                 \- io.zipkin.zipkin2:zipkin:jar:2.23.2:runtime
[INFO] +- org.cloudfoundry:cloudfoundry-operations:jar:5.9.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.cloudfoundry:cloudfoundry-client:jar:5.9.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.squareup.wire:wire-runtime:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.cloudfoundry:cloudfoundry-util:jar:5.9.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.atteo:evo-inflector:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.10.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.22:compile
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] \- org.cloudfoundry:cloudfoundry-client-reactor:jar:5.9.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.4:compile
[INFO]    +- com.github.zafarkhaja:java-semver:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO]    +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:jar:0.11.2:compile
[INFO]    +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:jar:0.11.2:runtime
[INFO]    +- io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:jar:0.11.2:runtime
[INFO]    \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
```

Base pom parent -

```
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.8</version>
   <relativePath/>
</parent>
```

Tomcat version in CF - `8.5.84`

SAP Machine JDK - `11.0.18_0.0.b0`

Any pointers will be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of trail and error, found the rootcause.

`Logback 1.4.5` does not support `javax.*` packages, instead searches for `jakarta.*` packages. Downgrading it to `1.2.x` fixed it.

Note - Logback `1.3.x` does not work with `Spring 2.7.8` hence downgraded to `1.2.x`

Ref - https://logback.qos.ch/dependencies.html